# Deploying a Bokeh server with Flask

Tags: python, bokeh

Trying to get a simple working panel/bokeh server on my web server.

I have embed.html

```
<head>
  {{ resources|safe }}
</head>


{% block content %}
<h1>Plot should be here.</h1>
<div>
  {{ div|safe }}
  {{ script|safe }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

panel_test.py

```
def sine(frequency, phase, amplitude):
    xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4)
    return hv.Curve((xs, np.sin(frequency*xs+phase)*amplitude)).options(width=800)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ranges = dict(frequency=(1, 5), phase=(-np.pi, np.pi), amplitude=(-2, 2), y=(-2, 2))
    dmap = hv.DynamicMap(sine, kdims=['frequency', 'phase', 'amplitude']).redim.range(**ranges)
    pn.serve(dmap, port=5006, allow_websocket_origin=["localhost:5000"], show=False,threaded=True)
```

main_test.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
application=app
# locally creates a page
@app.route('/')
def index():

    script = server_document(url='localhost:5006')
    # print(script)
    # use the script in the rendered page
    print("Session Pulled!", datetime.now())
    print(script)
    return render_template("embed.html", script=script)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # runs app in debug mode
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

After firing up panel_test.py I get confirmation that the panel is running

Which is great.  Then running my main_test.py on my server it seems to communcate with localhost but I get a webpage with just 'Plot should be here' (as expected) and nothing else.  Upon looking at the source code it looks like render_template has inserted the 'script' code (See below) but does not seem to be rendering the images:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.open('GET', "localhost:5006/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1002&bokeh-app-path=/localhost:5006&bokeh-absolute-url=localhost:5006", true);
  
  xhr.onload = function (event) {
    var script = document.createElement('script'),
    src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.response);
    script.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
xhr.send();
```

Has anyone encountered this?